# How to fix ‘textview data ’ error in android

Tags: java, android

I want to add the random number to put on textview in Dialogfragment that gets from Timer Activity;

i try to change many times

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt_v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
    txtv_2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textV_2);
    btn_str=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_give_str);

    dia=new DiagFragment();

    nBtb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);
    nBtb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            dia.show(MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
        }
    });


    timer.schedule(task, 1000, 5000);


}

TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        if (dia!=null){

            ((DiagFragment) dia).setData2(String.valueOf((Math.random() * 10)));

        }
    }
};


public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_dialog,null);
    mContext=getActivity();

    initView(view);

    return view;
}


public void initView(View view){
    tx1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
     tx2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txv_2);

}



public void setData2(String string) {

    str2=string;
    Log.w(TAG, "setData2: "+string );
    tx2.setText(string);
```

}

I can get data on diafragment, but I get an error when I add data to the TextVIew (tx2)

the error message is :

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.soundgil.dailogonclicklistend.DiagFragment.setData2(DiagFragment.java:68)
        at com.soundgil.dailogonclicklistend.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:54)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `tx2` was not found correctly so it null. Try checking the layout xml (is your view id correct?) or put it up.

By the way, `TimerTask.run()` was run in a sub thread so you can not update the UI. UI must be operated in main thread. Try to use a handler like this:

```java
Handler handler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message message){
        if (message.what == 0 && dia!=null){
             ((DiagFragment) dia).setData2(String.valueOf((Math.random() * 10)));
        }
    }
};

TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When Dialogfragment is not shown, tx2 is not initialized, invoke setText() on it will cause error. Please try checking null for tx2 in setData2().

```
public void setData2(String string) {
    str2 = string;
    Log.w(TAG, "setData2: "+string );
    if (tx2 != null) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tx2.setText(str2);     
            }
        });
    }
}
```